# How to Remove the Ethernet Network Connection?/

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

I Want to remove the ethernet Network which is without name and I'm not able to do that as there is no option to do that, when I click on it, It just hand and terminates the windows:

[image]

Comment: What does your PC display in Change Adapter Options? Please post a screenshot of the Network Connections screen in the Control panel. This looks like a virus/malware issue imo...

Comment: In the Change Adapter Options it shows only three Networks , Bluetooth,Ethernet, and Wireless Connection , that's it